# determine IP for device

Tags: linux-networking, subnet

I am configuring an eth1 interface on in Red Hat, but I don't understand exactly what the IP address should be.

I'm given an IP of 10.237.128.0/25.
This means that the NETMASK would be 255.255.255.128; I understand this portion.

What I don't understand, is if eth1 is in fact a host device, what would the IPADDR address be?

Here are my guesses:

```
10.237.128.0/25
10.237.128.0 (since the NETMASK variable will be declared, thus making /25 unnecessary)
10.237.128.1-126 (If eth1 is considered a host, 8 0-bits and 8 1-bits would be unavailable on the network as a host, and the 128 bit is the network.)
```

Comment: That can't be your IP address, as it's a network.

Comment: A /25 is 128 IP addresses...

Comment: http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=10.237.128.0&mask1=25&mask2=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your IP address can be anything from 10.237.128.1 to 10.237.128.126

```
Address:   10.237.128.0          00001010.11101101.10000000.0 0000000
Netmask:   255.255.255.128 = 25  11111111.11111111.11111111.1 0000000

Network:   10.237.128.0/25       00001010.11101101.10000000.0 0000000 
Broadcast: 10.237.128.127        00001010.11101101.10000000.0 1111111
HostMin:   10.237.128.1          00001010.11101101.10000000.0 0000001
HostMax:   10.237.128.126        00001010.11101101.10000000.0 1111110
Hosts/Net: 126                   (Private Internet)
```

Comment: So would IPADDR be the equivalent of Address, or your former statement?

Comment: @alrightgame: yes

Comment: Yes to which one?

Comment: It should be one of the addresses from HostMin to HostMax that isn't already taken. (So if someone gave you a gateway address, don't use that.)

Comment: @alrightgame: Anything between .1 and .126

Answer (score 4):

The last one (something in range of 10.237.128.1-126)

---

If a **network** has the address `10.237.128.0/25`, the number `25` refers to how many bits are contained in the network. From this, the number of bits left for address space can be calculated. As all IPv4 networks have 32 bits, and each “section” of the address denoted by the decimal points contains eight bits, “192.0.2.0/24” leaves seven bits to contain host addresses:

```
Netmask:   255.255.255.128 = 25  11111111.11111111.11111111.1 0000000
```

This is enough space for 126 host addresses. These host addresses are the IP addresses that are necessary to connect your machine to the Internet.

This is an adapted excerpt from this article: [Understanding IP Addressing and CIDR Charts | RIPE Network Coordination Centre](http://www.ripe.net/internet-coordination/press-centre/understanding-ip-addressing)